Union in Apache iceberg tables through time travel
I am trying to apply union for two iceberg tables which are fetched through time travel in pyspark.
This is the code that I tried:
union_query = f"""
    SELECT * FROM {table_name} FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '{initialdate}' LIMIT 1000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM {table_name} FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '{lastdate}' LIMIT 1000
"""
uniondf = spark.sql(union_query)

but it is throwing the following error :
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'UNION'.(line 3, pos 12)

== SQL ==
    SELECT * FROM glue.def.hugedata FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2024-10-08T09:06:51.932' LIMIT 1000
    UNION ALL
------------^^^
    SELECT * FROM glue.def.hugedata FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2024-11-05T13:16:44' LIMIT 1000

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(parsers.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractParser.parse(parsers.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:54)

Note:
Is there any possibility that the above query can work, as my requirement has to be those two iceberg tables should be fetched through time travel and has to be joined in single query.

The limit statement is the issue, or at least is an issue.  If you have to have the limit, use a  derived table - select * from (SELECT * FROM {table_name} FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '{initialdate}' LIMIT 1000) t limit ....`
